# PSBT encoding : what's the aim of convertBytes function?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip174-psbt

I'm currently working on PSBT and I try to understand all the part of the original implementation.

Dealing with base64 PSBT encoding: it seems that we convert the buffer from a base 8 to a base 6 using the [convertBytes](https://www.github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/src%2Futil%2Fstrencodings.h) function.

Is someone that could explain me the aim of this conversion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSBT uses [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding. As every Base64 character has *64 = 2<sup>6</sup>* possibilities, they can store 6 bits of information. The `ConvertBits` function you link to takes input bytes (which consist of 8 bits each), and rearranges them into groups of 6 bits, which are then mapped to the Base64 character set.

`ConvertBits<A,B>` is not converting from base-*A* to base-*B*; it is converting from base-*2<sup>A</sup>* to base-*2<sup>B</sup>*.